# CSS ".div + .anotherdiv" doesn't work how I need

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/f962zL0h/
Hey!
I want to click on card1, so it will scale up etc. (that's working). But I also need, to animate card2 and card3. But when i do this:

```
.card1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    margin: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 200px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
}

.card2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    margin: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 200px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 340px;
}

.card3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    margin: 0.5em;
    margin-top: 200px;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 675px;
}

.card1:active {
    margin: 0em;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

.card1:active + .card2 {
    transform: scale(0) translatey(1000px);
    opacity: 0;
}

.card1:active + .card3 {
    transform: scale(0) translatey(1000px);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

It is moving just with card2, not card3, but they've got same settings and everything.Thanks so much for any help guys!

Comment: + selecteur is for the very next , ~ this selecteur is for the many next, even if something else is in between. i believe you need .card1:active ~ .card3   https://jsfiddle.net/f962zL0h/1/

Comment: @GCyrillus's answer worked for me. Assuming you want the other two to disappear when you click on card one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work with `.card3` because `.card1` is not directly followed by `.card3`.

Instead use `~` selector:

```
.card1:active ~ .card2{
    transform: scale(0) translatey(1000px);
    opacity: 0;
}
.card1:active ~ .card3{
    transform: scale(0) translatey(1000px);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f962zL0h/2/).